# Grails - Hibernate.LONG in session.createSQLQuery

Tags: hibernate, grails

In my grails controller I am trying to use a SQL query to access a table as described in the two answers here:
[Query using alias on column give an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118703/query-using-alias-on-column-give-an-error)
[Hibernate criteria query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682683/hibernate-criteria-query)

The answers use Hibernate.LONG to specify the type of the column. When I use Hibernate.LONG in my controller action I get the following error:

```
Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Hibernate for class: org.example.Test.DashboardController
```

Searching google I see Hibernate.LONG used in many references, yet I can't discover how to enable it. What must I do to enable the use of Hibernate.LONG in my grails controller class? Using SpringSouce 1.3.7.

```
package org.example.Test

class DashboardController {
    def sessionFactory

    def testMysqlResult = {
        def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        def query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
            .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.INTEGER)
            .addScalar("NAME", Hibernate.STRING)
            .list()
        println query
        [query: query]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an import.  Try adding `import org.hibernate.Hibernate` below the `package org.example.Test`